# Systemd user doesn't see blackbox exporter config file

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm setting up monitoring with prometheus and the `blackbox_exporter` on a raspberrypi. I'm trying to get run the exporter through systemd.

I have a user called `blackbox`:

`/etc/passwd`:

```
blackbox:x:999:995::/home/blackbox:/bin/false
```

`sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/blackbox.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Blackbox Exporter Service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=blackbox
Group=blackbox
ExecStart=/home/pi/blackbox/blackbox_exporter --config.file==/home/pi/blackbox/blackbox.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The error:

```
Aug 10 17:02:51 monitor blackbox_exporter[1783]: level=error ts=2021-08-10T16:02:51.364Z caller=main.go:228 msg="Error loading config" err="error reading config file: open =/home/pi/blackbox/blackbox.yml: no such file or directory"
```

But the file is there:

```
ls -l blackbox
total 15496
-rwxrwxrwx 1 blackbox blackbox 15847084 May 10 13:59 blackbox_exporter
-rwxrwxrwx 1 blackbox blackbox      672 Aug  5 18:57 blackbox.yml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 blackbox blackbox    11357 May 10 14:04 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx 1 blackbox blackbox       94 May 10 14:04 NOTICE
```

Comment: There's a typo in your config path option.

Comment: I've been squinting at that path for hours and missing the double equals. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Typo, thanks user1686. I'd copied the path and did a `cat path/to/file`, and everything. Of course I was looking at the double equals without processing it.